# How can we overrider serializer.save() method in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have update functional view. And i'm update profile instance with serializer.save() method. I want to override that default save method. and want to save that in to profile managers file. Can you tell me how can i do that ?

**functional view where i'm using that save method.**

```
if request.method=="PUT":
        request.data["update_time"] = timezone.now()
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(profile, data=request.data,partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
```

**trying to move that in managers :**

```
def save_me(self,obj):
        obj = obj.save()
        return obj
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a update method in the serializer

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
    instance.content = validated_data.get('content', instance.content)
    instance.created = validated_data.get('created', instance.created)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```